# Make responsive 3 Graph with ChartJs

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, chart.js

I’ve got three charts and I’d like to get all this in more responsive.
On a phone or other screen.
Sometimes the charts superimpose on the vertical

You can find a screen with the 3 Charts.

[3 Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckUQy.png)

I use

```
var option: Chart.ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
```

index.html

```
       <div class="chart1">
            <canvas id="stub_pressureCanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart2">
            <canvas style=""id="stub_flowCanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart3">
            <canvas id="stub_volumeCanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Style.css

```
.chart1{
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.chart2{
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}


.chart3{
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 81.5%;
    left: 45.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: In that image the charts are not superimposed? Can you reproduce the problem in code, for example on JSFiddle or by including a working code snippet?

Comment: I can't use JSFiddle or a working code snippet but i can edit the post with a screen with my problem

Comment: To solve a code problem, it's best to post the code that produces the problem.